# Travis CI. Show results of SonarQube execution on Github

Tags: github, sonarqube, travis-ci

I've created GitHub repository, added Travis CI into it, added an icon with Travis CI build information (it works fine).

Also, I've added SonarQube via Travis CI. It also runs, but I didn't know how to show information from SonarQube execution in my Github README.rst.

Any ideas?

It will be amazing to show somehow all the data (technical debts, code smells, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [one of our sample projects](https://github.com/SonarSource/sq-com_example_java-maven-travis): in the [README file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SonarSource/sq-com_example_java-maven-travis/master/README.md), you will see how to integrate a badge that shows if your project passed the quality gate or not:

- The URL to get the badge itself:

> https://sonarqube.com/api/badges/gate?key=your_project_key

- The URL that points to your project:

> https://sonarqube.com/dashboard/index/your_project_key